# Send Dictionary of Data

Tags: python, json, django

Why isn't my `json` working? Do I need `json` to send a dictionary of data to my page?

Here is the code in question:

```
success: function(data) {
    var new_data = $.parseJSON(data);
    $('td#c00').html(new_data.img);
},
```

And

```
results = {'img':img, 'loc':match['number'][p]}
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(results))
```

I'm trying to send an img url and the number associated with it.

Eventually I want to be able to replace the 'td#c00' tag with one that changes based on the number I pass in through `json`.

Comment: any errors?  why do you use jquery and not just JSON.parse(data);?

Comment: I'm working with query throughout all of my code

Comment: So what is happening?  Nothing?  Are you checking a developer tool to see the value of `data`?

Comment: Did you set the `dataType` of `jQuery.ajax` to `json`?

Comment: That would make the data type the same going out and in right? I set it to POST

Comment: How do I extract the data from the new_data variable?

Answer (score -1):

This is how you do it:

```
var new_data = $.parseJSON(data);
$('td#c00').html(new_data['img']);
```

Comment: For the record, this is no different than the code in the question.  Javascript object properties can be accessed in either way: either by a period followed by the name, or as a string in a set of square brackets as an associative array.

Comment: Check out this link, or try it yourself: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html#link4

Comment: Strange how that doesn't work in my case... Maybe something to do with the parseJSON or jquery